# Internal error while loading to Bigquery table

Tags: google-bigquery

I ran this command to load 11 files to a Bigquery table:

```
bq load --project_id=ardent-course-601 --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON dw_test.rome_defaults_20140819_test gs://sm-uk-hadoop/queries/logsToBq_transformLogs/rome_defaults/20140819/23af7218-617d-42e8-884e-f213a583094a/part* /opt/sm-analytics/projects/logsTobqMR/jsonschema/rome_defaultsSchema.txt
```

I got this error:

> Waiting on bqjob_r46f38146351d545_00000147ef890755_1 ... (11s) Current status: DONE
>   BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'ardent-course-601:bqjob_r46f38146351d545_00000147ef890755_1': Too many errors encountered. Limit is: 0.
>   Failure details:
>   - File: 5: Unexpected. Please try again.

I tried many times after that and still got the same error.

To debug what went wrong, I instead load each file one by one to the Bigquery table. For example:

```
/usr/local/bin/bq load --project_id=ardent-course-601 --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON dw_test.rome_defaults_20140819_test gs://sm-uk-hadoop/queries/logsToBq_transformLogs/rome_defaults/20140819/23af7218-617d-42e8-884e-f213a583094a/part-m-00011.gz /opt/sm-analytics/projects/logsTobqMR/jsonschema/rome_defaultsSchema.txt
```

There are 11 files total and each ran fine.

Could someone please help?  Is this a bug on Bigquery side?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error reading one of the files: `gs://...part-m-00005.gz`

Looking at the import logs, it appears that the gzip reader encountered an error decompressing the file.

It looks like that file may not actually be compressed. BigQuery samples the header of the first file in the list to determine whether it is dealing with compressed or uncompressed files and to determine the compression type. When you import all of the files at once, it only samples the first file.

When you run the files individually, bigquery reads the header of the file and determines that it isn't actually compressed (despite having the suffix '.gz') so imports it as a normal flat file.

If you run a load that doesn't mix compressed and uncompressed files, it should work successfully.

Please let me know if you think this is not the case and I'll dig in some more.

Comment: I just retried loading all 11 part files.  I got the same error. The job id is bqjob_r52183c6a1cf5f984_00000147f0328319_1.  And I also  retried loading just part-m-00005.gz, and that worked fine.  The job id is bqjob_r535428744600a8ea_00000147f03335e0_1

Comment: Hi Jordan,  do you have any findings from your side?  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for providing those job is .. they were helpful. It looks like BigQuery was confused by a mix of compressed and uncompressed files. If you use the same compression type on all of your files, it should work. (I've updated my answer above).

Comment: Thank you for your help, Jordan. The files all have the same compression.  But the part-m-00005.gz file happens to be 0 in byte as they were generated by Hadoop mapreduce.  I guess I have to first delete that file, then, do the Bigquery upload.

Comment: Oh... interesting. I'll file a bug. Thanks for the report!