# Internal Error while loading Bigquery table

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm getting this type of error when loading a 1.3Gb json file with 10 million records using bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON

If I put only the first 1 million records into a separate file, it loads fine, but when I try to run on the full file, I get this:

> Current status: PENDING
>   Waiting on bqjob_r6ac3e4 BigQuery error in load operation: Error
>   processing job
>   'my-project-prod:bqjob_r6ac3e4da72b48e4f_000001528037b394_1': Too many
>   errors encountered. Limit is: 0. Failure details:
>   - File: 0: An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.

I've been able to load other large tables but always get this error when I go to load this one. Is there a way to troubleshoot this other than breaking the file into smaller and smaller pieces to try to find the offending line?

(similar to [Internal error while loading to Bigquery table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25390987/internal-error-while-loading-to-bigquery-table))

Comment: Did you tried later? Did you tried with a small file exactly in that location, it may be that for some reason cannot access the file in that bucket?

Comment: yes and yes. It doesn't appear to be a transient issue. Even if it was though, it would be great if there was a more informative error message, or some tool I could run to validate my input file.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at our logs about your job bqjob_r6ac3e4da72b48e4f_000001528037b394_1, seems like we can not read the first file (maybe other files as well, but it was complaining about the first one).

Is the file gzipped? We've seen similar error in the past when the file is somewhat incorrectly compressed.

Of course it could be other issues. But I don't have enough information right now. It would be helpful if you can share the other failed job id with us. I can help you check in our backend if those import job are failing consistently with file 0. Thanks!

Comment: thanks very much for looking into it! I'll have to check but I bet it's because I used bgzip instead of gzip.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the job in BigQuery's web UI, it should show you the first five errors. These may or may not be helpful.

In addition, you could set the maximum number of bad records allowed to a really high number (10,000,000). This way, the offending lines will simply be skipped and you could try to identify them by inspecting the result. (In the Java api, this is the method `JobConfigurationLoad.setMaxBadRecords(int)`, if you're using the command line it's the option `--max_bad_records=int`).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try increasing max-bad-records. 
When I look at the job in the Web UI, all I see right now is 
Error Reason:invalid. Get more information about this error at Troubleshooting Errors: invalid.
Errors:
An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.
Too many errors encountered. Limit is: 0.
Job ID: ....
Start Time: Jan 26, 2016, 6:45:51 PM
End Time: Jan 26, 2016, 6:46:22 PM
Destination Table: ...
Source URI: uploaded file
Source Format: JSON (Newline Delimited)
Schema:

Comment: No luck.  Using --max_bad_records 1000000 lead to the same error message, without any further details.

Comment: So now it says "Too many error encountered. Limit is 1000000"? Try setting it to a number larger than the number of rows in your file (that's why I suggested 10,000,000). That way you'll be able to tell whether the issue really is with specific lines.

Answer (score 0):

As per the link : 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#limitations

> Currently, when you load data into BigQuery, gzip is the only
>   supported file compression type for CSV and JSON files.

As you mentioned that you were trying to load bzip(which is not a supported format) you might be getting the error. Try unzipping the file and loading it, that might help.